# NavBar doesn't appear when segue is called programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, segue

I have an iOS app with 3 views. I am using a "push segue" to move between them. I have linked a push segue from a button in First view to Second View. For moving from second to third, I cannot have a button. I have a list of items and the person can click in any of those to move to third(and last) view. So I added a segue in storyboard and calls it programmatically. The third view is opening properly except that the nav-bar is no longer there.

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"moveToFilesSegue" sender: self];
```

I can live without nav-bar. But the real problem is that I cannot do a push segue from my third view to any other view.

So my question is whether there is a way to call a segue from second view to third view in such a way that the third view also has the navigation controller that the first two have by default(ie navbar is also visible in third segue). There is some break in navigation because of me calling a segue programmatically.

Comment: Could it be that your segue from from the second view to the third view is a modal segue? That would explain that the navbar gets hidden.

Comment: @Alex...No that's not the case. If I associate a push segue with a UIButton in 2nd view from storyboard and click on the button, the navBar appears in the 3rd view. But when I call the same segue programatically, the navBar disappears.

Comment: Ok, then what is self? Do you call performSegueWithIdentifier from within the UINavigationController or the ViewController of the second view?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between connecting the segue to a button or calling it manually with performSegue -- something else must be going on. Are you getting the  normal push animation when you call this (but just not seeing the navigation bar)?

Comment: @rdelmer...No I am not getting the normal push animation too( by push animation you mean slide from right to left animation??)

Comment: @Alex...the above code snippet is called from my second view upon click of a button generated programmatically(not from storyboard).

Answer (score 1):

So a few comments.  If you would like to be able to get to the two other views from any view at any point in time, then I would suggest using a tab bar controller rather than a navigation controller.

If you must use a navigation controller, then you should keep the first view controller as the root view controller.  Imagine then tapping a button that pushes the second view controller.  Then say you tap a button to get to the third view controller from the second.  What you should really do is perform an unwind segue from the second and then immediately perform a segue to the third.  The animations will be a bit undesirable by default since it will probably show the pop and the push, but to treat it like a tab bar, you could just disable the animations on the pop and push.

To implement, keep an int variable in the first view controller (btw.. you can do this by keeping the int in the navigation controller as well if you want).  In the viewDidAppear, check the int variable.  If it == 1 then push the second view controller.  If it == 2, then push the third view controller. Else, don't do anything.  When a button is pushed in the second view controller to view the third, unwind the second view controller, but in prepareForSegue set the int variable in the destination view controller to 2 .  Thus, when the first view controller appears, it will immediately push the third view controller.

I know it is a bit annoying, but you don't really want to keep pushing the same view controllers over and over again without unwinding.

Comment: Yes this is a bit annoying...For now I am using Modal segue and its working fine except for the animation (which I think I can change)...I will definitely try using tab bar controller...But I dont want to get to my 3rd view from 1st...My navigation is simple (1->2->3)...But when I was trying to go to 3rd view from 2nd view, the 3rd view was not embedded in the navigation controller somehow.
Thanks a lot for ur help